# Convert custom SELECT result into JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm missing something and can't seem to find anything that fits this scenario.  I want to output a custom `SELECT` query into a `VARIABLE` as `JSON`.

Given the following basic table and script I'm easily able to convert the results of a `SELECT` statement from a table into a `JSON` variable:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    [VALUE] nvarchar(100) Null
);

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT N'Value 1' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Value 2' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Value 3';

DECLARE @JsonValue nvarchar(max);
SELECT @JsonValue =
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @Table
    FOR JSON PATH
    , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
);
SELECT @JsonValue;
```

This happily outputs `JSON`:

```
[
    { "VALUE": "Value 1" },
    { "VALUE": "Value 2" },
    { "VALUE": "Value 3" }
]
```

Now, if I want to output a custom query:

```
DECLARE @JsonValue nvarchar(max);
SELECT @JsonValue =
(
    SELECT N'Value 1' AS [VALUE] UNION ALL
    SELECT N'Value 2' UNION ALL
    SELECT N'Value 3'
    FOR JSON PATH
    , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
);
SELECT @JsonValue;
```

I get:
`The FOR XML and FOR JSON clauses are invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table or common table expression or view and apply FOR XML or FOR JSON on top of it.`

Running just one part of the query:

```
SELECT N'Value 1' AS [VALUE] UNION ALL
SELECT N'Value 2' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Value 3'
FOR JSON PATH
, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

results in `JSON`:

```
[
    { "VALUE": "Value 1" },
    { "VALUE": "Value 2" },
    { "VALUE": "Value 3" }
]
```

I tried a few different things like JSON_QUERY, etc but it's all just failing.  I can use a CTE but that feels very overkill.  I've studied the documentation but I just can't seem to understand where I'm falling short so I'm hoping someone has the insight to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a bunch of `UNION ALL` queries, use `VALUES`:

```sql
DECLARE @JsonValue nvarchar(max);
SELECT @JsonValue =
(
    SELECT V.Value
    FROM (VALUES(N'Value 1'),(N'Value 2'),(N'Value 3'))V([Value])
    FOR JSON PATH , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
);
SELECT @JsonValue;
```

Or, alternatively, if you must use `UNION ALL`, then union the values in a sub query, and then use `FOR JSON PATH` outside of it:

```sql
DECLARE @JsonValue nvarchar(max);
SET @JsonValue = (SELECT [Value]
                  FROM (SELECT N'Value 1' AS [VALUE] UNION ALL
                        SELECT N'Value 2' UNION ALL
                        SELECT N'Value 3') U
                  FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES);
SELECT @JsonValue;
```

Comment: Ah, there we go, your second one is the one I need.  We don't have control over the incoming data, so wrapping it is the way to go.  Much appreciated.